# Get "unknown predicate `-delete" Error in script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

The following script I have saved in an *.sh* file on the server that clears a few directories of old files and directories.

```
#!/bin/bash

find /PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_1 -mtime +5 -type f -delete

find /PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_2 -mtime +5 -type f -delete

find /PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_3 -mtime +5 -type d -exec rm -rv {} +
```

This is the error message when I run the script:

> 'ind: unknown predicate `-delete

In addition to

> $'\r': command not found

I don't think the latter disturbs the code but the first one surely does.

Mind that I edit my code on Windows 10 and my server is an Ubuntu 64x run through Amazon Web Services (EC2).

Comment: Are you sure it says `ind:` and not `find:`? Run `dos2unix` on the script before running it in `Ubuntu` server.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue.

The problem was that my file was in dos format.

Using the command dos2unix on my file, solve the problem.